# База данных без базы данных

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, задача у меня странная. Необходимо сделать форму регистрации пассажиров, без использования баз данных, чисто C#. Как сделать так, чтобы  можно было вставить переменную в имя объекта класса Passenger.

P.s. мне надо сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать неограниченное количествово объектов *Passenger*, и о каждом из них хранить информацию. Прошу помощи.

```
using System;

namespace Avia_registration
{
class Passenger
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;
    public string country;
    public int age;
    public Passenger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give a name to your passenger");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Give a surname to your passenger");
        surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Where is " + name + " from?");
        country = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How old is " + name + " ?");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is information.");
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(surname);
        Console.WriteLine(country);
        Console.WriteLine(age);

    }

}
class Plane
{
    //future programme(Seats count)
}
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have got a plane with five seats, choose who will fly away");
        string[] Namelist = new string[5];  //тут будут хранится имена всех пассажиров, чтобы потом вывести на экран
                                            //список перед "отправкой"
        Passenger one = new Passenger();
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
}
```

P.s. Я только начинаю...

Comment: А чем вам БД не угодили ? чудес то не бывает, не будет БД придется писать в файл своего формата, потом придумывать поиск по этому файлу и т.п. и в итоге вам придется реализовать собственную БД ...

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Как создать список пассажиров? Как добавить в него элемент и убрать? Как сериализовать/десериализовать?

Comment: @Mike: Можно просто сериализовать список объектов, при старте грузить его в память, и искать по нему в памяти при помощи LINQ, линейным поиском. Ну или построить индексы (`Dictionary<string, Passenger>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сейчас создаёте массив определённой размерности для имён. Я предлагаю вам создавать массив определённой размерности для всех данных на пассажиров (это называется коллекция). Попробуйте для этого следующий код (обратите внимание на метод `Main()` и подключённые библиотеки):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Avia_registration
{
class Passenger
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;
    public string country;
    public int age;
    public Passenger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give a name to your passenger");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Give a surname to your passenger");
        surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Where is " + name + " from?");
        country = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How old is " + name + " ?");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is information.");
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(surname);
        Console.WriteLine(country);
        Console.WriteLine(age);

    }

}
class Plane
{
    //future programme(Seats count)
}
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have got a plane with five seats, choose who will fly away");
        List<Passenger>() passengersList = new List<Passenger>(5);  // тут будут хранится уже не только имена
                                                                   // а все данные на пассажиров
                                                                   // если в скобках указать число, то
                                                                   // коллекция будет создана числом этой размерности
        for (i = 0; i < passengersList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
            passengersList[i] = passenger; // так как коллекция расширяема (то есть это динамический массив),
                                           // мы можем добавить пассажира таким образом: passengersList.Add(passenger);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

[Документация по List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Если же вы хотите сохранить только имена, то это можно сделать таким образом:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have got a plane with five seats, choose who will fly away");
    string[] Namelist = new string[5];  //тут будут хранится имена всех пассажиров, чтобы потом вывести на экран
                                        //список перед "отправкой"

    for(i=0; i < Namelist.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Passenger one = new Passenger();
        Namelist[i] = one.name
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

В обращении к атрибуту и в грамотности написания точно не уверен, потому что давно с C# не работаю, но по идее всё верно